# Calloc causing fault when trying to allocate space. (Implementing virtual disk)

Tags: c

So I'm kinda noob in C, and i am implementing virtual disk for my semester project. I am trying not to use memset() for allocating the space but rather i'm trying to allocate it my self using calloc(), according to the user's requirement.

Here's my code for calloc:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

#define BLOCKS 1000

int main(){

     char *ip = NULL;
     if(ip = (char*)calloc(BLOCKS, sizeof(char)) == NULL){

        printf("Error in Malloc\n");
        exit(1);

    }

    *ip = 'a';

    free(ip);

}
```

I wrote this to check how calloc works, but every time I run this, I get "segmentation fault". Don't know whats causing it.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: BTW, you should use `perror` and `exit(EXIT_FAILURE)` to handle `calloc` failure.

Comment: Thanks. Will be using them from now :)

Comment: if the code were compiled with all the warnings enabled, then you have have seen two warnings messages.  Warnings should be fixed.  If you fix the warnings, then the code will not seg fault

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if(ip = (char*)calloc(BLOCKS, sizeof(char)) == NULL)
```

should be

```
if((ip = calloc(BLOCKS, sizeof(char))) == NULL)
```

Since `==` has more precedence than `=`, you need parenthesis. See the [operator precedence table](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B#Operator_precedence) And in C, [don't cast the result of `calloc`(and family)](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc)

Comment: my bad, It works fine now! Thanks alot.
But still i don't understand what the compiler was reading here?

Comment: `calloc` returned a pointer, the compaision between `NULL` and this pointer is done and then, this result is assigned to `ip`. In other words, `==` executed first, not `=`. This was the problem

Comment: It could be more readable to code in two statements: `char* ip = calloc(BLOCKS, sizeof(char));` then `if (!ip)`